# Where May I (legally) get a Mac OS X .iso File to Virtualize OS X?

Tags: macos, virtualization, virtualbox

I want to virtualize a Mac (the latest, 10.9) on my Mac (MacBook Air). I prefer to use VirtualBox. After setting up the OS X guest, I need to provide a .iso file from which VirtualBox will install OS X. Where can I (legally) get such a .iso file? My Mac didn't come with installation media so I can't just create one from a disc.

Comment: Sorry about the duplicate. I did a search but it was not specific enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These steps assume that you already have purchased OS X 10.9 through the Mac App Store.

1. Open the Mac App Store
2. Press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> Key and hold it during the following steps
3. Click at the purchased tab
4. Scroll to OS X Mavericks
5. Click at the Download button
6. If you already have OS X Mavericks installed, you will be asked if you want to continue
7. Click continue
8. Now, you can release the <kbd>Alt</kbd> Key

To get the dmg file:
1. Go to the downloaded install application in the applications folder
2. <kbd>Control</kbd>+click on the installer, and choose *Show Package Contents*, and choose *Show Package Contents*.
3. Navigate to `Contents > Shared Support`
4. The file you are looking for is called `InstallESD.dmg`

If you need a `.iso` file, you have to [convert it using Disk Utility](http://osxdaily.com/2012/07/18/convert-dmg-to-cdr-or-iso-with-disk-utility/)

Comment: Sadly, even after all that, I doubt the ISO will work with VirtualBox. From [this page](http://www.macbreaker.com/2014/05/os-x-mavericks-in-virtualbox-with-niresh.html): *Unfortunately, the standard "Unibeast" method for installing OS X Mavericks on PCs (which uses an official copy of the Mavericks installer) doesn't work with Virtualbox. Instead, you'll have to pirated "distros" of Mac OS X such as Niresh, which is now the most popular distro for Mavericks.*

Comment: For install info see http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/106840/5231

VirtualBox supports a Mac-style EFI boot when using the Mac OS X type choices with "Enable EFI" selected, so you can boot an unaltered OS install. However, as noted in the answer I linked, the InstallESD.dmg from the Mavericks App is just plain not a bootable disk image even on a real Mac, so workarounds are necessary.